# How to create selects and states dynamically on react using Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, list, select, state, material-ui

I need to create Select components based on a list of selects that i have, for example:

List -> item1, 
        item2

The component :

```
<Select 
  value={this.state."NAME OF THE ITEM ON THE LIST"}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
 <MenuItem value={X} key={X} > Something </MenuItem> (the MenuItem part is working)
</Select>
```

Since the `select component` needs a value and i need that value to be a `state`, so when it gets clicked it will call the method `handleChange` and will update the state like this:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        "THE NAME OF THE ITEM ": event.target.value(this comes from the MenuItem)
    });
};
```

How can i create the `state` dynamically so if i have a list with X itens it will create X `selects` and X `states` to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array property in your state to manage these items

```
state = {
    items: []
}
```

Then, when you are dynamically adding a select, you have to add a new value in this array

```
addItem = () => {
    this.setState({
        items: [
            ...this.state.items, // previous items
            { value: ""} // plus the new one
        ]
    });
};
```

And finally, when you render a Select

```
<Select
  value={this.state.items[index].value
  onChange={event => {
    this.setState({ // map over the array to modify the matching item
      items: this.state.items.map(
        (item, idx) =>
          idx === index ? {...item, value: event.target.value} : item
      )
    });
  }}>
```

Comment: in this part :  value={this.state.items[index].value}

Comment: Can u make a working example so i can compare with what i did?

Comment: Nevermind, just figure it out, but your answer give me the right path to follow, thanks

Comment: @LucioZenir What is `[index]`?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully below snippet will help you,

```
{this.props.data.map((e, keyIndex) => {
    return (<MenuItem key={keyIndex} value={e.warehouseId}>{e.name}</MenuItem>);
 })
}
```